# simple setInterval with paper.js not working

Tags: javascript, setinterval, paperjs

I'm trying to understand how to use setInterval with Paper.js. I made a simple test, with the same code inside a setInterval function and outside. It works on the latter case, but not when inside the setInterval. Any idea?

```
// interval (not working)//

var id = setInterval(function() {   
    var path = new Path.Circle(new Point(20, 20), 30);
    path.fillColor = 'red';
    var pointX = 80;
    var pointY = 50;
    var symbol = new Symbol(path);
    symbol.place(new Point(pointX, pointY));
    pointX = pointX+50;
    pointY = pointY+50;
    }
}, 1000);


//no interval//

var path = new Path.Circle(new Point(20, 20), 30);
    path.fillColor = 'red';
    var pointX = 80;
    var pointY = 50;
    var symbol = new Symbol(path);
    symbol.place(new Point(pointX, pointY));
    pointX = pointX+50;
    pointY = pointY+50;
    symbol.place(new Point(pointX, pointY));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/miguelrivero/2BzUL/10/

Thanks!

Comment: Your jsfiddle has a syntax error and it doesn't import the library it needs in order to run.  You haven't described what it is that goes wrong either.

Comment: corrected the jsfiddle, but no result. Maybe I'm not using the right way to include Paper.js? The idea is that the code draws a circle each second

Comment: You're declaring and re-initializing the (x, y) variables *inside* the interval handler, so every time it runs it will draw the circle at the same place. You should move those `var` declarations to *outside* the handler.

Answer (score 1):

The first reason is the extra `}` you have which is a syntax error.  The second reason[s] is that there are errors:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/paperjs/paper.js/master/dist/paper.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. fiddle.jshell.net/miguelrivero/2BzUL/10/show/:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } fiddle.jshell.net/miguelrivero/2BzUL/10/show/:40
Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/paperjs/paper.js/master/dist/paper.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:40
Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/paperjs/paper.js/master/dist/paper.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Path is not defined fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:29
Uncaught ReferenceError: Path is not defined
```

Comment: I corrected the jsfiddle, but no result. Maybe I'm not using the right way to include Paper.js? The idea is that the code draws a circle each second...

Comment: If you fix the `}` syntax error, does it then work outside of the fiddle?

Comment: No, it doesn't. At least not as expected. If I change the browser tab and return again to it, then I see them all.

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue.  What browser?

Comment: Firefox, Chrome ansd Safari behave the same. You can look at it at: http://www.miguelrivero.net/mainWeb/images/portafolio/exp/StreetHorrsing/web/

Comment: I've inserted the code in this larger test (also using paperjs). My goal is to make a form appear one by one when mouseover the cubes. The interactivity is not programmed yet. I want to make the setInterval work forst.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.miguelrivero.net/mainWeb/images/portafolio/exp/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
noRect = false
GET http://www.miguelrivero.net/mainWeb/images/portafolio/exp/StreetHorrsing/web/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 404 (Not Found) /mainWeb/images/portafolio/exp/StreetHorrsing/web/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.map:1

Comment: Yes, It was a failed loading. Corrected this but to no effect on the expected behavior.